Sequelize multiple column and multiple data search
Tables;
PostFilters
Posts
Filters;
[
  { tag: 'floorNumber', value: { [Symbol(or)]: [3] } },
  { tag: 'm2', value: { [Symbol(between)]: [100,500] } }
]

Sequelize Code;
      const filteredPosts = await Post.findAll({
        where: {
          categoryId: categoryWithSubcategoryIds,
        },
        include: [
          {
            model: PostFilter,
            where: {
              [Op.and]: filters,
            },
          },
        ],
        order: [
          [sorted.columnToSort, sorted.sortOrder], // Sıralama yapmak istediğiniz sütunun adı ve sıralama türü
        ],
        raw: true,
      });

Sql Executing;
Executing (default): SELECT "Post"."id", "Post"."user", "Post"."categoryId", "Post"."code", "Post"."title", "Post"."cover", "Post"."price", "Post"."description", "Post"."city", "Post"."district", "Post"."neighborhood", "Post"."favoriteCount", "Post"."viewCount", "Post"."status", "Post"."createdAt", "Post"."updatedAt", "PostFilters"."id" AS "PostFilters.id", "PostFilters"."postId" AS "PostFilters.postId", "PostFilters"."tag" AS "PostFilters.tag", "PostFilters"."value" AS "PostFilters.value" FROM "Posts" AS "Post" INNER JOIN "PostFilters" AS "PostFilters" ON "Post"."id" = "PostFilters"."postId" AND (("PostFilters"."tag" = 'floorNumber' AND ("PostFilters"."value" = '3')) AND ("PostFilters"."tag" = 'm2' AND "PostFilters"."value" BETWEEN '100' AND '500')) WHERE "Post"."categoryId" IN (7, 9, 8, 4) ORDER BY "Post"."createdAt" ASC;

Here's the problem;
(("PostFilters"."tag" = 'floorNumber' AND ("PostFilters"."value" = '3')) AND ("PostFilters"."tag" = 'm2' AND "PostFilters"."value" BETWEEN '100' AND '500'))

I want to search for more than one data on the same columns at the same time and comply with all the conditions I search for.
Expected Result:
The query result is to return data with id value 1 because I want to retrieve data with both m2 and floorNumber value 3, I need to retrieve data that meets both conditions at the same time.

"on the same columns"  not really sure what this means, and a the same time - this query or data time? Can you include a few rows of desired input, and expected results by editing question.

Yep, this is a typical problem with EAV model: you either need multiple  joins on your postfilters table or you need to use aggregation. See the duplicate question for answers.
